# Git for Windows not able to Authenticate

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-for-windows

A colleague has installed git for Windows via the Visual Studio installed instead of installing the standalone Git for Windows. I've re-installed Visual Studio Community edition and removed the Git installation from Visual Studio.

When trying to authenticate after running `git clone *our repo*` a Visual Studio sign in prompt appears. So, it is not using the Windows login. When trying to login with the Visual Studio prompt, their Visual Studio login does not work. Also, it opens an OpenSSH sign in prompt directly after the Visual Studio failed login which we also cannot sign into. My installation of git works fine and we tried uninstalling and re-installing it. I've checked environment variables with `set >> output.txt` to see if they were any different. They are not. I've checked git's credential helper and it is set to "manager" on both machines.

Why is his machine behaving so much different than mine? Why are the Visual Studio and OpenSSH login prompts popping up instead of just using Windows logins? I've even tried just storing logging credentials as plain text and using that for the git login, but that seems to do nothing. (It exhibits the same behavior.)

Any ideas on this? Ideally I'd like to reset every git setting to default and just have it use Windows login.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that updating to GCM 1.18.4 resolved the issue.

Github issue: [Credential Manager not working](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues/823)